# Adding bodyParser() hangs all api requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I need to edit request's body by adding few things in there during api proxy and the only way I can think off to do it is using body parser to gain access to `req.body`.

```
const compression = require('compression');
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

// Add body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Enable gZip compression
app.use(compression());

// Disable X-Powered-By header for security reasons
app.disable('x-powered-by');

// Add cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser());

// Example proxy
app.post('/api', (req, res) => {
  const url = 'https://my.api.com';
  req.pipe(request({
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    auth: {
      user: 'user',
      pass: 'password'
    }
  })).pipe(res);
});
```

However as soon as I add body parser api hangs, it is pending and then time outs. note I didn't add any body manipulations in the example yet, as I need to address this api hanging first.

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the **compression** middleware before **bodyParser** and add one more `bodyParser.urlencoded` just before `bodyParser.json` as below to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
// Enable gZip compression
app.use(compression());

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));

// Add body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Issue still remains

Comment: can you comment out the `compression` and check?

Comment: Still didn't fix it, issue seems to be coming from piping, using something like https://github.com/dominictarr/connect-restreamer I'll rewrite it slightly and use it

Comment: Hello @Ilja were you able to fix it